# What's the most efficient way to have documents with multilple fields representing the score in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a database of documents indexed in Elasticsearch. I want to provide somwhat personalized search results to users based on the user segment. User segment is defined by user country, language, etc. Number of segments can grow exponentially when adding a new dimension. For each pair of document-segment I compute the score using my own algorithm. I then want to rank those documents based on user segment.

To achieve this now, I store the documents' scores in a `nested` field with `{key: <segment_id>, value: <score>}`. I then can ask Elasticsearch to order documents by the `<segment_id>`. Currently, we are hitting the limit of Elasticsearch, especially when the number of segments grows.

Is there a better way to do it?